# CIContext, iOS 9 and memory issues

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, avfoundation, ios9

So I recently updated iOS to 9.0.2. 
I've been using RosyWriter, Apple's example to capture and filter video frames using CIFilter and CIContext. 
And it worked great in iOS 7 and 8. 
It all broke down in iOS 9.

Now memory report in RosyWriter and my app looks like this:
[image]

And eventually the app crashes.

I call **[_ciContext render: toCVPixelBuffer: bounds: colorSpace: ];** and **imageWithCVPixelBuffer**. Looks like CIContext has an internal memory leak when I call these two methods.

After spending about 4 days I found that if I create a new CIContext instance every time I want to render a buffer and release it after - this keeps the memory down. But this is not a solution because it's too expensive to do so.

Anyone else has this problem? Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you run an allocations (instruments) to see where the leak is?

Comment: No leaks shown in Instruments.

Comment: How and where are you testing? Tests using a Release configuration will give misleading results. Tests on the Simulator will give misleading results.

Comment: iPhone 6 plus and iPhone 4s, both debug and release all that - same results.

Comment: Okay, cool. Well, Allocations instrument (not Leaks instrument) will show you what the extra objects are and you can file a bug report. Plus it sounds to me like you can easily send them a project that demonstrates the bug, as it is their own project!

Comment: Did you file a bug with Apple for this?  Seeing the same issue.  Fine on iOS 8, huge memory leak in iOS 9.

Comment: Somebody already did, they fixed it in recent 9.1, check it out it should be fine now

Comment: I'm on 9.1, and I'm still getting serious leaks with `render(_:toMTLTexture:commandBuffer:bounds:colorSpace:)`...

Comment: @LucasTizma, I confirm. It's still there. Although they fixed something related but the main problem still there. Since I was still finding leaks on 9.1 but not as bad as before I decided to switch to entirely different approach in my code to get around the leak. Sorry, forgot to mention it here.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this memory leak still exists on iOS 9.2. (I've also posted on the [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17142).)

I get the same memory leak on iOS 9.2. I've tested dropping EAGLContext by using MetalKit and MLKDevice. I've tested using different methods of CIContext like drawImage, createCGImage and render but nothing seem to work.

It is very clear that this is a bug as of iOS 9. Try it out your self by downloading the example app from Apple (see below) and then run the same project on a device with iOS 8.4, then on a device with iOS 9.2 and pay attention to the memory gauge in Xcode.

Download 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013109

Add this to the APLEAGLView.h:20

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) CIContext* ciContext;
```

Replace APLEAGLView.m:118 with this

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
 _ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:_context];
```

And finaly replace APLEAGLView.m:341-343 with this

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);  

    @autoreleasepool  
    {  
        CIImage* sourceImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];  
        CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, sourceImage, nil];  
        CIImage* filteredImage = filter.outputImage;  

        [_ciContext render:filteredImage toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];  
    }  

  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorBufferHandle);
```

Comment: They say it's not a leak but a weird Xcode behavior. I'm not sure about that, because apps used to crash even when not in debugging mode.
The GPUImage community, they discuss it here:  https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/2093

Comment: Henrik have you made any progress on this? I also saw your comments on the SCRecorder repo on github. I'm experiencing the same issue and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: No @user3344977 I solved my problem by creating a custom video compositor. I'm not sure if this is an Xcode bug, as krafter pointed out, but when I tested it out it actually seemed to be so.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code after use context

```
context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
```

and release CGImageRef object also

```
 CGImageRelease(<CGImageRef IMAGE OBJECT>);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Krafter,

Are you writing custom filters?  I'm finding that dod works differently in iOS 9.

It looks like if dod.extent.origin.x and dod.extent.origin.y are not close to whole numbers stored as doubles (e.g. 31.0, 333.0), then the extent.size of the output image will be (dod.extent.size.width + 1.0, dod.extent.size.height + 1.0).  Before iOS 9.0 the extent.size of the output image was always (dod.extent.size). So, if (you are cycling the same image through a custom CIFilter over and over && your dod.extent isn't close to nice, even whole numbers) {you get an image whose dimensions increase by 1.0 each time the filter runs, and that might produce a memory profile like you have.}

I'm assuming this is a bug in iOS 9, because the size of the output image should always match the size of dod.

My setup: iOS v9.2, iPhone 5C and iPad 2, Xcode 7.2, Obj-C

Comment: What's dod? And no, no custom filters